# How can I encrypt a PHP variable (a link)?

Tags: php, url, variables, encryption, encode

I need help encoding a link. Basically, upon completion of an event, I run a function that redirects the user to a link. The link is taken directly from a PHP variable.

```
<?php 

$url = "http://google.com/";
$mylink = "<a href=\"" . $url . "\">";

echo $mylink;

?>
```

My question is, how can I echo $mylink, without having the $url shown in the source code. I want the output of my link to still go to $url, but not show the value of $url ANYWHERE in my source code.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you can do this: `$url = chr(104) . chr(116) . chr(116) . chr(112) . chr(58) . chr(47) . chr(47) . chr(119) . chr(119) . chr(119) . chr(46) . chr(103) . chr(111) . chr(111) . chr(103) . chr(108) . chr(101) . chr(46) . chr(99) . chr(111) . chr(109) . chr(47);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one sure way to do this: you could store in your database (or files on the server)  the link and an ID. Instead of the actual url, print a link to a php script you write which passes in that ID.  This page you write simply looks up the associated ID and uses a header to redirect to the link.

For Example: you write a script redirector.php then the links in the page source point to "redirector.php?id=10293".  The redirector script looks up what is id 10293 and sees http://www.example.com then calls

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

This way the links are only in the server side and never show up in your source code.  As user [pst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166390/pst) suggested in the comments you could also use something like tinyurl which operates on this same principal.

Any other methods will rely on some sort of encryption which could be decrypted because the actual data (link url) is in the page source albeit obscured.

**EDIT** :  here is an example of how you could write your two scripts -- the one which is printing the urls and the one which would redirect. Assuming a table urls exists in your MySQL db add a column called 'hash' or 'id' or something and in the script which will print the urls add the lines:

```
$hash = sha1($url);
mysql_query("UPDATE url_table SET hash = '$hash' WHERE url = '$url'");
$printURL = "../redirect.php?id=$hash";
print "<a href='$printURL'>click me to go somewhere you don't know yet</a>";
```

now in another file named redirect.php put the following code:

```
<?php
//connect to db or include files
$givenHash = $_REQUEST['id']; $realURL = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM url_table WHERE hash = '$givenHash'"); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $realURL = $row['url'];
}
header("Location: $realURL");
?>
```

This will either send them to the url you want if it is found in the db or drop them back to the page they were on before they clicked the link.  If you only have a few links that are known in advance then you can do this trick without the use of databases by just using a look up array.  Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to be a very viable answer, and easy because it does not even require encryption. If you really cannot store a map id -> url in your PHP, you might want to use the same forward, but with a HTTP request containing the URL encoded, base64 encoded, encrypted URL. A would recommend a mapping scheme though, much easier (replace the serial id with a SHA-1 hash over the URL if you dont want to have people try out stuff).

Comment: Thanks a lot @hackartist and owlstead. I appreciate it a LOT. Unfortunately, I'm a noob in PHP. Would you mind giving me a quick example as to how I would do this?

Comment: Sure thing.  If you have a lot of urls, then I assume you already have some way to store them (database or text file).  If it is only a few then you could just do it in the php source code as a small array.  At anyrate take the url and put it through the [one way hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) sha1() and store that result.  I will update my answer above with the code (I am assuming MySQL but if not then tell me the constraints of your system and about how many urls you are planning to use)

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with javascript, and some encryption like TEA.

Something like...

Include TEA function in javascript

```
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
/*  Block TEA (xxtea) Tiny Encryption Algorithm implementation in JavaScript                      */
/*     (c) Chris Veness 2002-2010: www.movable-type.co.uk/tea-block.html                          */
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
/*  Algorithm: David Wheeler & Roger Needham, Cambridge University Computer Lab                   */
/*             http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/ftp/papers/djw-rmn/djw-rmn-tea.html (1994)                 */
/*             http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/ftp/users/djw3/xtea.ps (1997)                              */
/*             http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/ftp/users/djw3/xxtea.ps (1998)                             */
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */

var Tea = {};  // Tea namespace

/*
 * encrypt text using Corrected Block TEA (xxtea) algorithm
 *
 * @param {string} plaintext String to be encrypted (multi-byte safe)
 * @param {string} password  Password to be used for encryption (1st 16 chars)
 * @returns {string} encrypted text
 */
Tea.encrypt = function(plaintext, password) {
    if (plaintext.length == 0) return('');  // nothing to encrypt

    // convert string to array of longs after converting any multi-byte chars to UTF-8
    var v = Tea.strToLongs(Utf8.encode(plaintext));
    if (v.length <= 1) v[1] = 0;  // algorithm doesn't work for n<2 so fudge by adding a null
    // simply convert first 16 chars of password as key
    var k = Tea.strToLongs(Utf8.encode(password).slice(0,16));  
    var n = v.length;

    // ---- <TEA coding> ---- 

    var z = v[n-1], y = v[0], delta = 0x9E3779B9;
    var mx, e, q = Math.floor(6 + 52/n), sum = 0;

    while (q-- > 0) {  // 6 + 52/n operations gives between 6 & 32 mixes on each word
        sum += delta;
        e = sum>>>2 & 3;
        for (var p = 0; p < n; p++) {
            y = v[(p+1)%n];
            mx = (z>>>5 ^ y<<2) + (y>>>3 ^ z<<4) ^ (sum^y) + (k[p&3 ^ e] ^ z);
            z = v[p] += mx;
        }
    }

    // ---- </TEA> ----

    var ciphertext = Tea.longsToStr(v);

    return Base64.encode(ciphertext);
}

/*
 * decrypt text using Corrected Block TEA (xxtea) algorithm
 *
 * @param {string} ciphertext String to be decrypted
 * @param {string} password   Password to be used for decryption (1st 16 chars)
 * @returns {string} decrypted text
 */
Tea.decrypt = function(ciphertext, password) {
    if (ciphertext.length == 0) return('');
    var v = Tea.strToLongs(Base64.decode(ciphertext));
    var k = Tea.strToLongs(Utf8.encode(password).slice(0,16)); 
    var n = v.length;

    // ---- <TEA decoding> ---- 

    var z = v[n-1], y = v[0], delta = 0x9E3779B9;
    var mx, e, q = Math.floor(6 + 52/n), sum = q*delta;

    while (sum != 0) {
        e = sum>>>2 & 3;
        for (var p = n-1; p >= 0; p--) {
            z = v[p>0 ? p-1 : n-1];
            mx = (z>>>5 ^ y<<2) + (y>>>3 ^ z<<4) ^ (sum^y) + (k[p&3 ^ e] ^ z);
            y = v[p] -= mx;
        }
        sum -= delta;
    }

    // ---- </TEA> ---- 

    var plaintext = Tea.longsToStr(v);

    // strip trailing null chars resulting from filling 4-char blocks:
    plaintext = plaintext.replace(/\0+$/,'');

    return Utf8.decode(plaintext);
}

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */

// supporting functions

Tea.strToLongs = function(s) {  // convert string to array of longs, each containing 4 chars
    // note chars must be within ISO-8859-1 (with Unicode code-point < 256) to fit 4/long
    var l = new Array(Math.ceil(s.length/4));
    for (var i=0; i<l.length; i++) {
        // note little-endian encoding - endianness is irrelevant as long as 
        // it is the same in longsToStr() 
        l[i] = s.charCodeAt(i*4) + (s.charCodeAt(i*4+1)<<8) + 
               (s.charCodeAt(i*4+2)<<16) + (s.charCodeAt(i*4+3)<<24);
    }
    return l;  // note running off the end of the string generates nulls since 
}              // bitwise operators treat NaN as 0

Tea.longsToStr = function(l) {  // convert array of longs back to string
    var a = new Array(l.length);
    for (var i=0; i<l.length; i++) {
        a[i] = String.fromCharCode(l[i] & 0xFF, l[i]>>>8 & 0xFF, 
                                   l[i]>>>16 & 0xFF, l[i]>>>24 & 0xFF);
    }
    return a.join('');  // use Array.join() rather than repeated string appends for efficiency in IE
}


/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
/*  Base64 class: Base 64 encoding / decoding (c) Chris Veness 2002-2010                          */
/*    note: depends on Utf8 class                                                                 */
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */

var Base64 = {};  // Base64 namespace

Base64.code = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

/**
 * Encode string into Base64, as defined by RFC 4648 [http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648]
 * (instance method extending String object). As per RFC 4648, no newlines are added.
 *
 * @param {String} str The string to be encoded as base-64
 * @param {Boolean} [utf8encode=false] Flag to indicate whether str is Unicode string to be encoded 
 *   to UTF8 before conversion to base64; otherwise string is assumed to be 8-bit characters
 * @returns {String} Base64-encoded string
 */ 
Base64.encode = function(str, utf8encode) {  // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648
  utf8encode =  (typeof utf8encode == 'undefined') ? false : utf8encode;
  var o1, o2, o3, bits, h1, h2, h3, h4, e=[], pad = '', c, plain, coded;
  var b64 = Base64.code;

  plain = utf8encode ? Utf8.encode(str) : str;

  c = plain.length % 3;  // pad string to length of multiple of 3
  if (c > 0) { while (c++ < 3) { pad += '='; plain += '\0'; } }
  // note: doing padding here saves us doing special-case packing for trailing 1 or 2 chars

  for (c=0; c<plain.length; c+=3) {  // pack three octets into four hexets
    o1 = plain.charCodeAt(c);
    o2 = plain.charCodeAt(c+1);
    o3 = plain.charCodeAt(c+2);

    bits = o1<<16 | o2<<8 | o3;

    h1 = bits>>18 & 0x3f;
    h2 = bits>>12 & 0x3f;
    h3 = bits>>6 & 0x3f;
    h4 = bits & 0x3f;

    // use hextets to index into code string
    e[c/3] = b64.charAt(h1) + b64.charAt(h2) + b64.charAt(h3) + b64.charAt(h4);
  }
  coded = e.join('');  // join() is far faster than repeated string concatenation in IE

  // replace 'A's from padded nulls with '='s
  coded = coded.slice(0, coded.length-pad.length) + pad;

  return coded;
}

/**
 * Decode string from Base64, as defined by RFC 4648 [http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648]
 * (instance method extending String object). As per RFC 4648, newlines are not catered for.
 *
 * @param {String} str The string to be decoded from base-64
 * @param {Boolean} [utf8decode=false] Flag to indicate whether str is Unicode string to be decoded 
 *   from UTF8 after conversion from base64
 * @returns {String} decoded string
 */ 
Base64.decode = function(str, utf8decode) {
  utf8decode =  (typeof utf8decode == 'undefined') ? false : utf8decode;
  var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, d=[], plain, coded;
  var b64 = Base64.code;

  coded = utf8decode ? Utf8.decode(str) : str;


  for (var c=0; c<coded.length; c+=4) {  // unpack four hexets into three octets
    h1 = b64.indexOf(coded.charAt(c));
    h2 = b64.indexOf(coded.charAt(c+1));
    h3 = b64.indexOf(coded.charAt(c+2));
    h4 = b64.indexOf(coded.charAt(c+3));

    bits = h1<<18 | h2<<12 | h3<<6 | h4;

    o1 = bits>>>16 & 0xff;
    o2 = bits>>>8 & 0xff;
    o3 = bits & 0xff;

    d[c/4] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2, o3);
    // check for padding
    if (h4 == 0x40) d[c/4] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2);
    if (h3 == 0x40) d[c/4] = String.fromCharCode(o1);
  }
  plain = d.join('');  // join() is far faster than repeated string concatenation in IE

  return utf8decode ? Utf8.decode(plain) : plain; 
}


/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
/*  Utf8 class: encode / decode between multi-byte Unicode characters and UTF-8 multiple          */
/*              single-byte character encoding (c) Chris Veness 2002-2010                         */
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */

var Utf8 = {};  // Utf8 namespace

/**
 * Encode multi-byte Unicode string into utf-8 multiple single-byte characters 
 * (BMP / basic multilingual plane only)
 *
 * Chars in range U+0080 - U+07FF are encoded in 2 chars, U+0800 - U+FFFF in 3 chars
 *
 * @param {String} strUni Unicode string to be encoded as UTF-8
 * @returns {String} encoded string
 */
Utf8.encode = function(strUni) {
  // use regular expressions & String.replace callback function for better efficiency 
  // than procedural approaches
  var strUtf = strUni.replace(
      /[\u0080-\u07ff]/g,  // U+0080 - U+07FF => 2 bytes 110yyyyy, 10zzzzzz
      function(c) { 
        var cc = c.charCodeAt(0);
        return String.fromCharCode(0xc0 | cc>>6, 0x80 | cc&0x3f); }
    );
  strUtf = strUtf.replace(
      /[\u0800-\uffff]/g,  // U+0800 - U+FFFF => 3 bytes 1110xxxx, 10yyyyyy, 10zzzzzz
      function(c) { 
        var cc = c.charCodeAt(0); 
        return String.fromCharCode(0xe0 | cc>>12, 0x80 | cc>>6&0x3F, 0x80 | cc&0x3f); }
    );
  return strUtf;
}

/**
 * Decode utf-8 encoded string back into multi-byte Unicode characters
 *
 * @param {String} strUtf UTF-8 string to be decoded back to Unicode
 * @returns {String} decoded string
 */
Utf8.decode = function(strUtf) {
  // note: decode 3-byte chars first as decoded 2-byte strings could appear to be 3-byte char!
  var strUni = strUtf.replace(
      /[\u00e0-\u00ef][\u0080-\u00bf][\u0080-\u00bf]/g,  // 3-byte chars
      function(c) {  // (note parentheses for precence)
        var cc = ((c.charCodeAt(0)&0x0f)<<12) | ((c.charCodeAt(1)&0x3f)<<6) | ( c.charCodeAt(2)&0x3f); 
        return String.fromCharCode(cc); }
    );
  strUni = strUni.replace(
      /[\u00c0-\u00df][\u0080-\u00bf]/g,                 // 2-byte chars
      function(c) {  // (note parentheses for precence)
        var cc = (c.charCodeAt(0)&0x1f)<<6 | c.charCodeAt(1)&0x3f;
        return String.fromCharCode(cc); }
    );
  return strUni;
}

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
```

Then for testing create an html anchor element, and set it's vale by de-crypting a pre-calculated encrypted string

```
document.body.innerHTML = "<a href='no_access' id='targetElement'>the link</a>"
// pre-calculated result: AAvpH77xTCdBO/qAb5yHOFVF3vlbi1XS6Dd5eA==
// By doing: Tea.encrypt('http://secret.encrypted.url/','some_password')

document.getElementById('targetElement').href=Tea.decrypt('AAvpH77xTCdBO/qAb5yHOFVF3vlbi1XS6Dd5eA==','some_password')
```

Comment: It's a solution, but as the key is not secret, it will simply amount to obfuscation. You might just as well just Base64 encode/decode it.

Comment: Yes it is, and yes you could.